# Connection closed by [ip] port 22 (ssh)

Tags: git, ssh

Не могу разобраться, в чем причина.
Пытаюсь сделать git pull/push/clone. Пару дней назад началась эта проблема, терминал продолжительное время думает, потом выдаёт `Connection closed by [ip] port 22` (fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.)

Через мобильный интернет все работает.
В настройках роутера, системы (линукс) ничего не менял. Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794   попробуйте это

Comment: Пробовал, но не помогло :(